# forest prediction folium how to print only one value in a band

Tags: folium, google-earth-engine

We are predicting the forest position on a earth engine map.

Our output is (256,256,1)

The unique band of our prediction has 1 band with 0 and 1.

We would like to show only the 1 in folium but the layer we have is showing both zeros and ones ...

```
folium.TileLayer(
    tiles=mapid['tile_fetcher'].url_format,
    attr='Google Earth Engine',
    overlay=True,
    name='predictions',
  ).add_to(map)
map.add_child(folium.LayerControl())
map
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mask out the 0's using the `.mask()` function.